# Unknown marker with pytest-bdd only when parameter is declared

Tags: pytest, pytest-bdd, pytest-markers

When I declare a marker in `pytest.ini` having a parameter, this is not recognized in pytest-bdd feature file. Markers without parameters seem to work fine.

```
[pytest]
markers = 
    swr(issue1): link to Software Requirement
    smoke: Smoke Test component
```

Simple feature file works fine with **@smoke**:

```
Feature: Trivial Example
    @smoke
    Scenario: Add a number to another number
        Given 7 is set
        When 9 is added
        Then new value is 16
```

Fails with **@swr("123")**:

```
Feature: Trivial Example
    @swr("123")
    Scenario: Add a number to another number
        Given 7 is set
        When 9 is added
        Then new value is 16
```

Failure is a warning:

```
../../../../../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytest_bdd/plugin.py:127
  /home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytest_bdd/plugin.py:127: PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.swr("123") - is this a typo?  You can register custom marks to avoid this warning - for details, see https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/mark.html
    mark = getattr(pytest.mark, tag)
```

Comment: Also of note if I step into the collection `request.node.own_markers` I see a marker named "swr(123)" with empty args and kwargs rather than a marker named swr having an arg 123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look in the known [issues](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-bdd/issues/166) in the repository I stumbled upon something that is related. The developer mentions there is a hook available which is seen [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-bdd/blob/master/src/pytest_bdd/hooks.py#L37).

In the `conftest.py` we can then do the following:

```
from typing import Callable, cast
import pytest
import ast

def pytest_bdd_apply_tag(tag: str, function) -> Callable:
    tree = ast.parse(tag)
    body = tree.body[0].value
    if isinstance(body, ast.Call):
        name = body.func.id
        arg = body.args[0].value
        mark = getattr(pytest.mark, name).with_args(arg)
    else:
        mark = getattr(pytest.mark, tag)
    marked = mark(function)
    return cast(Callable, marked)
```

Then we can just register the marker as `swr` and the hook should automatically parametrize the function as needed. It uses `ast` to parse the marker and dynamically create the new marker. Shown below is what `mark` looks like when running with `swr` or `swr("123")`.

```
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.6, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ***, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: bdd-6.1.1
collecting ... 
MarkDecorator(mark=Mark(name='swr', args=('123',), kwargs={}))
collected 1 item
```

---

```
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.6, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ***, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: bdd-6.1.1
collecting ... 
MarkDecorator(mark=Mark(name='swr', args=(), kwargs={}))
collected 1 item
```

Take note of `MarkDecorator` in the output for each of the calls.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to solve the issue.   If I change pytest.ini to:
`markers = 
    swr: link to Software Requirement`

This works:

`@swr 
    Scenario: Add...
`

But this still fails:

`@swr("123") 
    Scenario: Add...
`
with:

`"PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.swr("123") - is this a typo?"`

Comment: @amhest updated the answer based on some more digging